# VLOOKUP formula based on 2 different values instead of 1

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I need to fill in a cell with a value (account number) based on 2 different values (`account name` and `department name`) in 2 columns.

I have a table with account name in column `A`, `Department number` in column `B` and the lookup value which is `Account number` in column `C`  because I have duplicate account name such as salaries in different departments and I want to differ between these accounts by account number.

Comment: Welcome! Is it "account number" is real number, not a text string? Well, what about SUMIFS() or MAXIFS() function?

Comment: Or FILTER the values based on the two criteria: `=FILTER(C:C, (A:A=x)*(B:B=y))`

Comment: This works for me:  `=XLOOKUP(AccName & DeptName, Acc_Column & Dept_Column, AccNum_Column)` - e.g. `=XLOOKUP(F3 & G3,$A$3:$A$10 & $B$3:$B$10,$C$3:$C$10)`